# Why do require the `path` module in `nodejs`?

Tags: node.js

I would like to understand the `path` module from `nodejs` as testing I running my app, using `path` and without the `path` - both are working as expected. in this case why should I use the `path` module. Because all tutorials guide to use the `path` module.

here is my code with 2 options:

```
var
    express     = require('express'),
    path        = require('path'),
    app         = express();

//option 1 using path!
app.get('/', function( req, res ){

    res.sendFile( path.join(__dirname + '/index.html' ) );

})

//option 2 no path module.
app.get('/', function( req, res ){

    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html' );

})

app.listen(8080);
console.log('app listens')
```

Comment: on your first example you are using ```path.join``` incorrectly, you should pass 2 parameters not one

Comment: They surely would use `path.join(__dirname, '/index.html' )` not `path.join(__dirname + '/index.html' )`?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainly it provides helpers to deal with paths in different environments, as Window vs Linux.

As stated in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path):

> The default operation of the path module varies based on the operating system on which a Node.js application is running. Specifically, when running on a Windows operating system, the path module will assume that Windows-style paths are being used.

It also is useful to avoid typos when using slashes, retrieve extension names, the last dirname in a path etc.

Answer (score 1):

It takes care of the slashes hence recommended to use.

`path.join('xxx/','yyy')` `path.join('xxx/','/yyy')`, `path.join('xxx','yyy')` `path.join('xxx','/yyy')` will always give you `xxx/yyy.`

Answer (score 0):

The first variant is invalid. Should be:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
```

Such way all path segments will be joined with correct path separator which is OS dependant.

Comment: Doesn't `require` normalise path separators anyway?

Comment: This is not what require do. Require includes modules. And Nodejs reads files from file system with `fs` module which is under the hood of sendFile method.

Comment: Ah, right, it's Windows that normalises them, slashes work everywhere.